# Load html files locally into Chromium

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My long term goal for this is to have a construct 2 application embedded into a winform.

I've been following this tutorial:

http://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/

Problem is, I'm new to actual application development and have been doing exclusively game creation stuff for 10 years now, so all of this is brand new to me.

I'm stuck about halfway through the article, where it tells you to follow the link about using Local Files in CefSharp (can't post the link because I need 10 reputation and I'm a total noob)

If you're using C#.

I'm unsure of what any of this means. I'm unsure of what to do with this code or how to follow along. The link to the "ISchemeHandler" 404's. I'm not exactly how to elaborate on what I'm trying to say, which is unfortunate because I'd imagine someone would need more information than what I'm giving, it's not much to go off of.

The end goal for me here to to be able to do

local://myfolder/myfile.html

instead of

http://mywebsite(dot)com

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and feel free to ask questions if I need to elaborate on anything.

Comment: do you wanna access file in your local machine?

Comment: @null1941 Yes, in my local machine. I also need this to be portable.

Comment: your question is not clear.. i can't understand it